# Why Java/.NET allows every object to act as a lock?

Tags: java, .net

I'm currently writing my own VM, and have been looking at Java and .NET bytecode (as well as several other VMs) lately. If I understand this correctly, Java and .NET allows every object to act as it's own lock. .NET through it's "lock" keyword, Java through synchronized functions.

Is there a specific reason this is done? I was thinking of just doing it like C/C++ where you have a dedicated semaphore object/type you lock on too. This way I don't require any extra overhead per object. I am curious however, why .NET and Java has choosen this, and would like to make an informed decision when it comes to my own VM.

Comment: I don't think this "Why Java is designed the way it is" is really on topic.

Comment: [Identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184843/why-did-java-and-c-sharp-add-intrinsic-lock-to-every-object).

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is meant by "Java and .NET allows every object to act as it's own lock."?
Note: As I dont have reputation!!! I can't place comment.

Comment: @user3017587 the OP means that any object can be used with the `lock` keyword (or similar)

Comment: It is a good question, and personally I'd prefer if `Monitor` (thinking .NET here) was an instance type rather than a static type, and you needed a `Monitor` to do this. But: see existing question.

Comment: @dystroy yeah, mod feature

Comment: Java made the decision to make multi-threaded support a builtin of the language rather than leaving you to you own devices.  This adds some overhead but also has some performance advantages in that the JVM intrinsically understands how the multi-threading works and can optimise it e.g. with lock coalessing of inlined code (something C/C++ cannot do)

Comment: @Peter, the VM would still understand multi-threading if a semaphore was a specific VM type, and you had bytecodes for lock/unlock... Or would it? :S

Comment: From the linked question, it seems it's there for convinience.

Comment: I agree that the linked question asks the same question, but none of the answers actually answer it.

Comment: There is nothing in the language which states how locking is implemented/performed.  AFAIK It adds very little to the size of the header so the per object overhead is very small. Locking is optional in Java and C# so you don't gain much by forcing the developer to add a field to perform the locking, but you make it harder for the compiler to optimise locking by doing so.

Comment: For multi-threaded programs the overhead for each locked object can be lower. e.g. the JVM can use one proper lock for objects in an address range with a flag for each object. i.e. it add a bit to each object and only one lock for a block of objects.  Doing this in C/C++ automagically is very difficult as its not easy to combine fields from multiple objects which don't know anything about each other.

Comment: The reason this is impossible in c/c++ is because c/c++ does not have a JIT, and because threads are implemented as a library (before C11/c++11 at least). I don't think it will be difficult to optimize threading in a JIT which has a designated lock-type, and bytecodes to lock/unlock. In both cases you can prove that locking isn't required, and can optimize it out. It seems that the way .NET and Java handles locking is mostly about developer convinience than anything else...

Comment: in order to easily convert existing unsynchronized class into synchronized one.